# How to display a solution with using timelimit in CPLEX for scheduling(CP)

Tags: cplex, mixed-integer-programming, time-limiting

Now I am trying to get a solution within a specific time-limit in my code.

Actually, my problem(scheduling) is NP-hard.

It spends lots of time to get a solution or out of memory.
So, I set a time-limit in my code(60s) and I'd like to get a solution(scheduling) solved for 60s.

Is it possible?

If possible, please let me know.

Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can stop after a time limit

In OPL you would write

```
execute {
        cp.param.timelimit = 60;
}
```

You have the same parameter for all APIs

Comment: Sir, I used that code in my iteration mod file. But it doesn't give a solution(real schedule), but only give an Objective function value.

I mean, simply, I want to get a solution 'OP-value like 23.254", I want to get a solution schedule with decision variation like

[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]

Thank you, sir.

Comment: Additionally, it could be a little fundamental question,
if it is possible, why do we use a technique of heuristic for that kind of problem? 

I mean, most of the timelimit solutions by MILP(CPLEX) better than a heuristic solution.

Thank you, sir.

Comment: Hi, if you use OPL and CPLEX , in the postprocess part you may print any results through writeln functions in execute blocks See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1fb27039-328b-48eb-8be0-b73cdfbd69c3